# How do you stored screen_name from the twiiter api in python?

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to store screen_name from the twitter API so it can be stored in a file, however it is part of the user attribute. Could anyone advise on what i should code in my python script if im storing screen_name to a dictionary?
An example tweet is....

u'user': { u'name': u'Chris D', u'lang': u'ru', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 0, u'screen_name': u'cdraven87', u'notifications': None, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Mon Nov 10 11:33:57 +0000 2014', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': None, u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Mon Nov 10 11:55:00 +0000 2014', u'filter_level': u'medium', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}

My code is:

```
        dictionary['screen_name'] = tweet['screen_name']
        dictionary['favourites'] = tweet['favourites_count']
        dictionary['followers'] = tweet['followers_count']
```

Comment: I don't get the point. What do you want to achieve? You copy some key/value pairs of `tweet` to another dictionary. Do you want to save the `dictionary` to a file? If so, use `pickle`.

Comment: I want to save the screen name, favourites_count, and followers_count to the dictionary. However these are sub attributes of user. All the attributes that describe the tweet are stored in my variable tweet from the twitterAPI. The problem is seperating the sub attributes from the user attribute...

Comment: Then get the dict of `user` first with `tweet['user']['screen_name']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the dictionary under the `user` key, you can chain them:

```
dictionary['screen_name'] = tweet['user']['screen_name']
```

And btw. these `user` and `screen_name` **are not called attributes**, they're **keys** in the dictionary.

Comment: ictionary={}
            dictionary['tweet'] = tweet['text']
            dictionary['id'] = tweet['id']
            dictionary['created_at'] = tweet['created_at']
            json_data = json.dumps(dictionary)  
            
            saveFile = open('tweetBitcoin.json','a') #a=append
            saveFile.write(json_data)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()

Comment: Forget about `pickle` then.

Comment: The issue is that I cant save the screen_name attribute because it is a sub attribute of user...

Comment: Thanks, just saw it now. Cheers pal, ill give it a go